Should I avoid creating classes and compiling them at runtime in Android?
Let' say I have an app that is more or less like an editor and executor of what was created with the editor function.
I thought about two ways: I can either develop an algorithm and a structure to perform my job or I can literally write and compile at runtime .java file.
To get a better idea of what I am saying I will create a simplified example.
First case scenario, I will create multiple instances of SpecialMove for each creation by the user:
public class SpecialMove{
private String name;
private Type type;
private int damage;
...
}

In the second case scenario, classes that extend SpecialMove would be written and compiled at runtime:
    public class SpecialMove{
        protected Type type;
        protected int damage;
        ...
        }

//this class will be written into a separate file and compiled at runtime
    public class FireBall extends SpecialMove{
        protected Type type;
        protected int damage;
        ...
        }

In the past I've chosen to use the second case scenario but it was an application for desktop. Since I am not much skilled in Android, I would like to ask you if generating Dalvik byte code might be trickier and/or less efficient and in general any pros and cons.

Runtime code generation is banned by the Play Store.  You can download scripts in a sandbox like Javascript, but you can't download or compile native code at  runtime.  If caught doing it your app will be removed.  This is a security policy by Google to reduce the risk of malware and trojan horses.
In fact in general compiling code at runtime, on any platform, is almost certainly a wrong choice.  Sounds like a debugging nightmare.  You might sometimes download extentions with a plugin system, but you wouldn't be compiling it live.

What you mean by "but you wouldn't be compiling it live"? An app with a plugin architecture usually download and compile code ad runtime, am I wrong?

@JadeKush No, normally you precompile it once and download the bytecode/compiled library code.  You wouldn't compile it on the client.  There's no reason to complicate the client with a compiler.
